# How to stop AfterFunc before executing in Golang

Tags: go, timer, debouncing

```
var funcTimer *time.Timer

func AddItem(){

   defer funcTimer.Stop()

   funcTimer = time.AfterFunc(1000*time.Millisecond, func() {

        fmt.Println("Executed")

   })

}
```

My goal is trying to make this function as a debounce, in a way that if it is called rapidly without a time delay, the func call will not run.

My problem here is `funcTimer.Stop()` does not seem to stop `time.AfterFunc` function

In javascript, the equivalent of this is by using ClearTimeout and SetTimeout.

Answer (score 2):

Try https://github.com/bep/debounce:

the [code](https://github.com/bep/debounce/blob/master/debounce.go) is short enough to follow:

```
func New(after time.Duration) func(f func()) {
    d := &debouncer{after: after}

    return func(f func()) {
        d.add(f)
    }
}

type debouncer struct {
    mu    sync.Mutex
    after time.Duration
    timer *time.Timer
}

func (d *debouncer) add(f func()) {
    d.mu.Lock()
    defer d.mu.Unlock()

    if d.timer != nil {
        d.timer.Stop()
    }
    d.timer = time.AfterFunc(d.after, f)
}
```

to use:

```
debounces := New(100 * time.Millisecond)

debounces(func(){fmt.Println("a")})
debounces(func(){fmt.Println("b")})
debounces(func(){fmt.Println("c")}) // last one wins
```

https://play.golang.org/p/SOTB-VaGzWC

Comment: hello, i already tried this one but to no avail, here is the golang playground link https://play.golang.org/p/h8B4XX4a9qm

nothing outputs instead.

Comment: Updated answer with a playground link. You need to add a wait for the last debounce to win - otherwise the program exits before the timer fires.